# Change the auto increment amout in a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, auto-increment

Is there a way to make a foreach loop increment by more than one? I am loading a jquery script before each item in a foreach loop and I want the delay to increase by 300 for each item, so that each item animates separately as opposed to at the same time.

So is there another method other than $i++? Like $i++ + 300? Or I am reaching a little too far on this one?

---

Thanks everyone for responding so quickly. The $i+=300 was exactly what I was looking for. I used this variable to increase the delay time on each of the scripts so it is executed one at a time on each item in the loop. Here is a link to what I used it for. Thanks again!

http://cloudninelabs.com/c9v10/portfolio/

Comment: You tagged it with PHP, but it seems like you're talking about JavaScript. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to look after the counter yourself.

For example:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $somelist as $index => $content ) {
     // Do something with $content using $i
     $i += 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
foreach (array(1, 2, 3, 4) as &$value) {
    $value = $value + 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda unclear to me, but it seems like you can simply use `i*300` as your animation interval (e.g. `foreach ($foo as $i => $bar) { /*simply use $i*300 as your interval here*/ }`)

However, just FIY, n a regular `for` loop you can use `$i+=300` (e.g. `for ($i=0; $i<10000; $i+=300)`. It doesn't make much sense to do anything like that in an `foreach` loop. Instead, keep a separate variable to keep track of that and increase that be 300 every time (`$i=0; foreach ($foo as $bar) { ... $i+=300 }`).